# Is there any way to fix input lag?

Tags: cube-world

So I just purchased Cube World and it has become pretty unplayable for me. The game take seconds to respond to key presses and clicks (which then causes bad FPS). It doesn't seem like it should be too CPU/GPU intensive, and I've never had this problem with a game before. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Cube world seems to be having a lot of [problems](http://kotaku.com/the-current-status-of-cube-world-and-why-fans-are-worr-1449026160) perhaps its on their end?

Comment: May be true, might not be optimized. I mean it is still only alpha... But my computer isn't too low-end and I'm sure others are running it just fine.

Comment: I've had this issue when exploiting a glitch (rapid fire crossbow), but when playing normally It doesn't happen. Does the input lag happen on normal play?

Comment: Yepp nonstop. If I'm doing nothing, not even moving the mouse, the game runs smoothly. As soon as I try to move the character or camera FPS drops horribly and usually takes at least a second to respond. I tried turning down my key repeat speed as I've seen some people claim it helped, but I saw no change